# Ansible jinja test list if contains valid IP address and generate template

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have the following variables in Ansible:

```yaml
my_allowed_hosts2:
  - {host: patch, address: '202.167.24.50'}
  - {host:localhost, address: '::1/128', extra_field: trust}

my_ferm_groups:
  - firewall_whitelist1
  - firewall_whitelist2
```

I have a task that checks if there are valid IP addresses in `my_allowed_hosts2` and if so, generate a template for it  (in this case, the host I'm running the playbook against is in `firewall_whitelist2` group in my inventory). This template is then used to generate *ferm/iptable* rules to allow the IP addresses in `my_allowed_hosts2` to access the host.

However, if there is no valid address in `my_allowed_hosts2`, I don't want to generate a template for it (`firewall_whitelist_2`) even though `myhost` is a valid member of that group - because if it has no valid IP addresses that the template will become invalid. Hope I'm making sense so far.

The relevant tasks :

```yaml
- set_fact:
    valid_addresses: "{{ my_allowed_hosts2|json_query('[*].address')| map('ipaddr')|reject('match','^127.0.0.1|::1/128') | list }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ valid_addresses }}"


- name: Loop dictionary and copy group configs in place
  template: src=etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.j2 dest=/etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.conf owner=root group=root mode=0640
  when: item in my_ferm_groups
  with_items: "{{ group_names | reject ('match','^firewall_whitelist2$') if valid_addresses is not any }}"
```

What I was trying to do above is trying to remove `firewall_whitelist2` from the loop if there is no `true` value tested in `my_allowed_hosts2` list - thus preventing it to create that particular template.

However, I receive the following error :

> ```
> fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {
>    "msg": "the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated to false and no else section was defined."
> }
> ```

What I am expecting (IF `valid_addresses` is **not** empty) is something like the below. The template gets copied accordingly:

> ```
> ok: [myhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "checksum": "21f42490d91da92c6f404a30df6e34373266b72f", "dest": "/etc/ferm/ferm.d/firewall_whitelist1.j2", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "item": "firewall_whitelist1", "mode": "0640", "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/ferm/ferm.d/firewall_whitelist1.conf", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0", "size": 570, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
>
> changed: [myhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "checksum": "985d207faa196b285c20c7f60f6aa69b23f908b9", "dest": "/etc/ferm/ferm.d/firewall_whitelist2.j2, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "item": "firewall_whitelist2", "mode": "0640", "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/ferm/ferm.d/firewall_whitelist2.conf", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0", "size": 705, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
> ```

I tried this too in an effort to add `firewall_whitelist2` to the list so the template only gets generated when `valid_addresses` is not empty:

```yaml
- name: Loop dictionary and copy group configs in place
  template: src=etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.j2 dest=/etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.conf owner=root group=root mode=0640
  when: item in my_ferm_groups
  loop: "{{ group_names + 'firewall_whitelist2' if valid_addresses|length > 0 else group_names }}"
```

But this errors out with

> ```
> FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ group_names + 'firewall_whitelist2' if valid_addresses|length > 0 else group_names }}): can only concatenate list (not \"str\") to list"}`
> ```

Any idea how can I make this work?
Basically I'm trying to find a way to only generate that template for `firewall_whitelist_2` ONLY IF the condition matches (valid IP addresses detected in `my_allowed_hosts2`).
Any nudge in the right direction would help.

Comment: In the loop, what is the expected result? Simplify the loop by using *debug*. For example `- debug: var: item ...` Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes me feel like you are trying to fit in the `loop` what should be in the `when`.

So in the ultimate end you will probably loop on an empty array, when you could as well loop on a populated list and skip all items.

When moving all those conditions in the `when`, we could end up with:

```yaml
- template: 
    src: /etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.j2 
    dest: /etc/ferm/ferm.d/{{ item }}.conf 
    owner: root 
    group: root 
    mode: 0640
  when:
    - item in my_ferm_groups
    - item != 'firewall_whitelist2' or valid_addresses|length > 0
  loop: "{{ group_names }}"
```

---

Here is are two examples of this:

- When there is no matching IP

  ```yaml
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: no

    tasks:
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ item }}"
        when:
          - item in my_ferm_groups
          - item != 'firewall_whitelist2' or valid_addresses|length > 0
        loop: "{{ group_names }}"
        vars:
          valid_addresses: []
          group_names:
            - firewall_whitelist1
            - firewall_whitelist2
            - firewall_whitelist3 
            - firewall_whitelist4
          my_ferm_groups:
            - firewall_whitelist1
            - firewall_whitelist2
            - firewall_whitelist3
  ```

  This gives the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist1) => {
      "msg": "firewall_whitelist1"
  }
  skipping: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist2) 
  ok: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist3) => {
      "msg": "firewall_whitelist3"
  }
  skipping: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist4) 

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- When there is any matching IP

  ```yaml
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: no

    tasks:
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ item }}"
        when:
          - item in my_ferm_groups 
          - item != 'firewall_whitelist2' or valid_addresses|length > 0
        loop: "{{ group_names }}"
        vars:
          valid_addresses:
            - 10.1.1.1
          group_names:
            - firewall_whitelist1
            - firewall_whitelist2
            - firewall_whitelist3 
            - firewall_whitelist4
          my_ferm_groups:
            - firewall_whitelist1
            - firewall_whitelist2
            - firewall_whitelist3
  ```

  This gives the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist1) => {
      "msg": "firewall_whitelist1"
  }
  ok: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist2) => {
      "msg": "firewall_whitelist2"
  } 
  ok: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist3) => {
      "msg": "firewall_whitelist3"
  }
  skipping: [localhost] => (item=firewall_whitelist4) 

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

---

With all this, the `valid_addresses` you are populating stays as you have it right now.

Answer (score 2):

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        valid_addresses: "{{ my_allowed_hosts2|
                             json_query('[].address')|
                             map('ipaddr')|
                             difference(['127.0.0.1', '::1/128']) }}"
    - debug:
        var: valid_addresses
```

gives

```yaml
    "valid_addresses": [
        "202.167.24.50"
    ]
```

Is this probably the loop you're looking for?

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ group_names|difference(['firewall_whitelist2']) }}"
      when:
        - item in my_ferm_groups
        - valid_addresses|length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for that Vladimir! Sorry for not explaining better. But I think you almost got what I'm looking for. I do want to loop through `group_names` but I want to remove `firewall_whitelist2` from the list so that the template doesnt get copied, if `valid_addresses|length > 0`. If this condition is not satisfied, I still want it to iterate through the list and copy the other files, just not `firewall_whitelist2`.

Comment: I've updated my question too to hopefully show what I meant. When I used the loop that you gave as an example above, the loop gets iterated but even though the condition was met (there was a valid IP address in `valid_addresses`, it somehow still doesnt copy the template for `firewall_whitelist2` even though it copies others...